# How do I enable Geany's plugin manager

Tags: lubuntu, geany

I'm running Lubuntu and installed Geany.

In the Tools menu I don't have the Plugin Manager entry. I tried a few ways and I couldn't get it.

Can anyone help me to bring it on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me with Lubuntu 14.04 and Geany 1.23.1:

Open Geany. Click on `Edit`, `Preferences` and, in there, view the `Startup` tab. Make sure "Enable Plugin Support" is ticked. Click `Apply`. You should now see the Plugin Manager as an entry in the Tools menu.

Changing this option will need to restart Geany.

Comment: So simple but so efficient. Just a very tiny improvement: One should get out and in again.

Comment: If you like the answer, just click the little grey **☑** which means "yes, this answer is valid. If you like the answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow... **;)**